# Combine gnu-parallel and curl in Linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, gnu-parallel

I'm testing my webserver and sending API Thousand of request to optimize my program with high traffic. Indeed I write two bash-shells but they not fast as I want any one can help me on this and let me know how to modify them to execute fast as much as possible?

```
$ mycurl() { contents=$(< data.txt); eval "words=( $contents )"; arguments=(); for i in {1..1000}; 
do arguments+=( "${words[@]}" ); done; curl "${arguments[@]}"; }; 
$ export -f mycurl; 
$ seq 100 | parallel -j0 mycurl
```

and the second one is

```
$ for i in $(seq 100000); do cat data.txt; done | curl -K -
```

One way that I can run on my computer is the following but I am not sure it is the best way.

```
 mycurl() { parallel -j0 bash :::: <(ls job{1..2}.sh) };
 export -f mycurl;
 seq 10 | parallel -j0 mycurl;
```

Comment: Is your client maxing out its CPU power? If not, then increase `seq 10` until it is maxed out. If GNU Parallel starts warning about limitations, lift those limits.

Comment: @OleTange Dear Ole many thanks for the comment. Indeed the client I am working on has 20 GB of memory and 10 CPUs. I was wondering how can run my two shell script parallel and then again call then in another parallel command.

Comment: Is your client maxing out its CPU power? If not, then increase seq 10 until it is maxed out. If GNU Parallel starts warning about limitations, lift those limits.